# How can I use the JSON format of flair for my website?

Tags: support, flair

From [the flair page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair), it is mentioned that it is available in JSON format. How can I use its response for my website similar to the JSONP example? If it's not possible, why?

Answer (score 2):

Hm... you mean like server-side?

Here's some code in PHP that does the equivilant of the JSON example:

```
<?php
$flair_json_url = 'http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/100835.json';
$flair_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($flair_json_url));
?>
<div id="so-flair">
    <div id="gravatar"><?php print $flair_data->gravatarHtml; ?></div>
    <div id="reputation"><?php print $flair_data->reputation; ?></div>
    <div id="badges"><?php print $flair_data->badges; ?></div>
    <div id="displayname"><?php print $flair_data->displayname; ?></div>
    <a id="profileurl" href="<?php htmlspecialchars($flair_data->profileUrl); ?>">Visit my profile</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Using JavaScript only if it's possible. If it's not possible using JavaScript only, why?

Comment: What part of the [JSON example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair#json) on the flair page are you having problems with?

Comment: It's a JSONP example. I'm looking for an example for client-side processing of the JSON.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300130/explanation-and-usage-of-jsonp & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128520/ajax-vs-json-cross-domain-built-in-security-question

Comment: Thanks headvyd. That explains it.